# Python - Select lines in dataframe that appear in a second data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes, with the same number of columns and different number of rows.

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame([['ABS', 'CVDFSDF'], ['ADFG', 'EDFGSDF'], ['ASDC', 'VSDVDSF']], columns=['A', 'B'])

dfB = pd.DataFrame([['Awer', 'qkui'], ['EDF', 'HFG'], ['AB', 'LOI']], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

dfA:

```
    A   B
0   ABS CVDFSDF
1   ADFG    EDFGSDF
2   ASDC    VSDVDSF
```

dfB:

```
    A   B
0   Awer    qkui
1   EDF HFG
2   AB  LOI
```

I want to remove all the lines in dfA that do not include substring value appear in dfB.
I am only interested in column A.

So for my example above, I would have left only with the first row as 'AB' appear in second row of dfB is a substring of the first row in dfA.

Can someone assist me here?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with join all values of `dfB['A']` with `|` for regex `or` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = dfA[dfA['A'].str.contains('|'.join(dfB['A'].dropna().astype(str)), na=False)]
print (df)
     A        B
0  ABS  CVDFSDF
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. When running your solution on my actual data, the following error received -  'TypeError: sequence item 122: expected str instance, NoneType found'. Can I force Python to handle data as string?

Comment: @anky_91 - Thank you, added.

Comment: @dear_tzvi - Added `dropna` for remove `None` and `NaN`s and then convert to strings, also added `na=False` if `dfA['A']` are None or NaNs